# Verilog: How to perform Logical operations on a vector with single bit

Tags: verilog

Like an enable logic, I want to perform a logic operation on the whole vector like so:

```
input en;
input [7:0] a;

wire [7:0] enabledA;

assign enabledA = en & a;
```

where `enabledA[i] = en & a[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generate construct and for loop:

```
genvar i ;

generate

   for (i = 0 ; i <= 7 ; i = i + 1) begin
       assign enabledA [i] = en & a [i] ;
   end

endgenerate
```

Or you can simply write:

```
assign enabledA = {8{en}} & a ;
```

`{}` is used as replication operator here.

Comment: thank you very much, replication might be better

Comment: Also `assign enabledA = en ? a : 0;`

Comment: @dave_59 true, but I was going for a more general approach, like also for xor, or, nand, nor etc